# WCF Operation not supported in WCF Test Client because it uses type

Tags: wcf

When I try to import a WSDL (http://ns.hr-xml.org/schemas/org_hr-xml/3_0/Services/Web_Services/WSDL/TimeCard.wsdl) via WCF Test Client I get the "

> WCF Operation not supported in WCF Test Client"

because it uses type " error message as shown on screenshot.
[image]

The contract looks like below, I'm not sure why I'm getting above error message. Could some one please guide me to right direction:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="ChangeTimeCard", ReplyAction="*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ConfirmBODType), Action="ChangeTimeCard", Name="ConfirmBOD", Namespace="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(BinaryObjectType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(AmountType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(QuantityType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(PreferenceABIEType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(AddressBaseType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(NameType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(PersonNameBaseType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(TimePeriodABIEType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(TextType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(CodeType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(StatusBasisType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(VerbType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ResponseCodeType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(IdentifierType))]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(BusinessObjectDocumentType))]
        HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ProcessTimeCardResponse ChangeTimeCard(HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ChangeTimeCardRequest request);
```

And this is the ChangeTimeCardRequest  class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class ChangeTimeCardRequest {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.hr-xml.org/3", Order=0)]
        public HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ChangeTimeCardType ChangeTimeCard;

        public ChangeTimeCardRequest() {
        }

        public ChangeTimeCardRequest(HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ChangeTimeCardType ChangeTimeCard) {
            this.ChangeTimeCard = ChangeTimeCard;
        }
    }
```

Below is the ChangeTimeCardType:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.hr-xml.org/3")]
    public partial class ChangeTimeCardType : BusinessObjectDocumentType {

        private ChangeTimeCardDataAreaType dataAreaField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public ChangeTimeCardDataAreaType DataArea {
            get {
                return this.dataAreaField;
            }
            set {
                this.dataAreaField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("DataArea");
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, if wsdl doesn't work in WCF Test Client, does it mean it won't work for all clients ie. Java or php?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that WCF doesn't understand the type HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ChangeTimeCardType. Where is the code for the HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ChangeTimeCardType class?

Comment: thanks and I've updated my original question with the code for HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ChangeTimeCardType class

Comment: Can you try adding [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(HRXMLTimeCard.HRXML_Candidate_3_1.ChangeTimeCardType))] To your contract?

Comment: @Myagdi - Is your issue resolved ? I am facing the same problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without any serialization parameters ? (ex: removing [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)])